# how to convert Array to String in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array `$scope.userDays`looking like this:

```
$scope.userDays = [2,3,4,5,6];
```

need to take only the values and convert them into a string. The desired output would be something like this:

```
$scope.userDays ="2,3,4,5,6"
```

Comment: `myArray.join(",")`

Comment: This has nothing to do with AngularJS. That's something you can do purely  using JavaScript

Comment: Thanks yes Its working @Alnitak

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript Join() is use to convert array into string. You should try this:

```
    $scope.userDays = $scope.userDays.join() ;
```

If the above doesnot work then you should try the below function

```
    function createStringByArray(array) {
        var output = '';
        angular.forEach(array, function (object) {
            angular.forEach(object, function (value, key) {
            output += key + ',';
            output += value + ',';
    });
});
return output;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `join()` as follows

```js
var userDays = [2,3,4,5,6];
userDays = userDays.join(',');
alert(userDays);
```